# How to read data from client ESP8266-01?

Tags: esp8266

I need help: my Arduino is not receiving or reading from an ESP8266-01 as a client.

Actually, the ESP01-server and ESP01-client are successfully talking each other but if I attach the Arduino Uno to read the data from the server, nothing happens. It's not receiving at all.

Any help is very much appreciated.

[image: NodeMCUPyFlasher]
[image: im using ESplorer IDE]
Lua server:

```
-- GMKSoft
--*************************
--    ESP8266 Server
--*************************

--*************************
--  Static Configuration
--*************************
cfg =
{
    ip="192.168.255.101",
    netmask="255.255.255.0",
    gateway="192.168.0.1"
}
wifi.ap.setip(cfg)

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP);
wifi.ap.config({ssid="GMKSoft",pwd="GMKSoftESP"});
print("Server IP Address:",wifi.ap.getip())

sv = net.createServer(net.TCP) 
sv:listen(8080, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(conn, receivedData) 
        print("Received Data: " .. receivedData)         
    end) 
    conn:on("sent", function(conn) 
      collectgarbage()
    end)
end)
```

Client lua:

```
-- GMKSoft
--*************************
--    ESP8266 Client
--*************************

--*************************
--  Static Configuration
--*************************
client_ip="192.168.255.102"
client_netmask="255.255.255.0"
client_gateway="192.168.0.1"

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.setphymode(wifi.PHYMODE_N) 
wifi.sta.config("GMKSoft","GMKSoftESP") -- connecting to server
wifi.sta.connect()
if client_ip ~= "" then
    wifi.sta.setip({ip=client_ip,netmask=client_netmask,gateway=client_gateway})
end 

tmr.alarm(1, 2000, 1, function()

     if(wifi.sta.getip()~=nil) then
          tmr.stop(1)
          print("Connected!")
          print("Client IP Address:",wifi.sta.getip())
          cl=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
          cl:connect(8080,"192.168.255.101")

          tmr.alarm(2, 5000, 1, function() 
            cl:send("Hello World!")                  
          end)

         tmr.stop(2)
         print("Going to sleep")
         wifi.sta.sleeptype(wifi.MODEM_SLEEP)
      else
         print("Connecting...")
      end
end)
```

Arduino Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: I would lower the baud rate on the software serial port to 9600.  Other posts on this site suggest ESP to SoftwareSerial works better at that speed.  (You obviously need to lower ESP serial speed too)

Comment: Thank you dda for your comment, I try to lowering the bauad to 9600 of the softwareserial and hopefully I get a reading of data from ESP8266-01.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully communicate with two esp01 module as a AP and STATION.

The esp01 as a server, please flash it using NodeMCU-PyFlasher-2.1, and used this bin file nodemcu-master-7-modules-2017-11-23-15-58-17-integer.bin

I build it from  [here](https://nodemcu-build.com/)

Here is the code of the server, I'm using ESPPlorer IDE lua script:

```
cfg={}
cfg.ssid="GMKWiFi"
cfg.pwd="GMKSoft2627"

dhcp_config ={}
dhcp_config.start = "192.168.1.100"
wifi.ap.dhcp.config(dhcp_config)

print("ESP8266 Server")
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP);
wifi.ap.config(cfg);
print("Server IP Address:",wifi.ap.getip())

sv = net.createServer(net.TCP) 
sv:listen(80, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(conn, receivedData) 
        print(receivedData)         
    end) 
    conn:on("sent", function(conn) 
      collectgarbage()
    end)
end)
```

Here is the Client Code, Im using Arduino IDE

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid     = "yourSSID";         // SSID
const char* password = "yourpassword";     // Password
const char* host = "192.168.4.1";         // Server IP
const int   port = 80;                    // Server Port
const int   watchdog = 5000;              // Watchdog frequency
unsigned long previousMillis = millis(); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if ( currentMillis - previousMillis > watchdog ) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    WiFiClient client;

    if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
      Serial.println("connection failed");
      return;
    }

    String url;
    url += "R1";

    client.print(url);
  }
}
```